# iOS UITableViewCell asynchronous image download and change UITableView height accordingly with the use of auto layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, asynchronous, imagedownload

I'm writing an application where images are downloaded asynchronously and when the images are loaded its scaled but I just want to show as the same size within the UITableViewCell.

Since i'm using auto layout I have tried to change the height constraint through an IB but then I have to change the height of the cell and I though of reloading each cell after downloading each image but not sure if it's a good idea.

Its like the Facebook application where images are loaded and the uitableviewcell is dynamically changed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this delegate method?:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // return downloadedimage.bounds.height etc.
    }
```

Also do not forget to reload data in the viewDidLoad method

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I tried the problem is that the images are downloaded asynchronously so i don't exactly know what the actual size of the image is and each image is downloaded while scrolling so i cant reload the table after each image is downloaded

Comment: try reloading data in viewDidLayoutSubviews()